# Tkinter - why I must click the cross 2 times before the window has been closed

Tags: tkinter, toplevel, tkmessagebox

When I create a `subwindow (toplevel)`, I can't close the main window with one click. I must to click on cross and OK as many `times(+1)` as I called function about:

```
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *


def cross():
    if tkMessageBox.askokcancel(u"Quit ATTA Convertor ?", "Are you sure you want to close the window ?"):
        mainwin.quit()

def about():
    subwin = Toplevel(mainwin)
    subwin.mainloop()

mainwin = Tk()
mainwin.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", cross)

mainMenu = Menu(mainwin)
mainMenu.add_command(label="about...", command=about)
mainwin.config(menu=mainMenu)

mainwin.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you've called `mainloop()` twice. Remove the call to `subwin.mainloop()`,  you don't need it. A proper tkinter program should call `mainloop()` exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

You are running 2 mainloop events. You should remove the one in the `about()` method.

```
def about():
    subwin = Toplevel(mainwin)
    #subwin.mainloop() <- Remove this
```